# How to connect the leaflet.js to the Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, openstreetmap

How to connect a vanilla library in a Vue.js and then connect plugins.
I know there is a library - https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/. But there is limited functionality and there are not all the necessary plugins.

I have a sandbox where I tried to connect both the map and the plugin - https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-gagarin-6od2q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I got your question right. You can just use leaflet in Vuejs just by importing it.

```
import L from "leaflet"

//omitted basic vue structure
data: () => ({
    theMap: null,
}),
mounted(){
    this.init()
}
methods:{
    init(){
        this.theMap = L.map("yourId", {})
        //...Your other codes and options
    }   
},
```

And dont forget to include your leaflet css

```
<style src="leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"></style>
```

Comment: Thank you. How to connect a third-party plugin, for example?
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable
your example throws an error - "Error: Map container not found."
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-gagarin-6od2q?from-embed=&file=/src/App.vue

Comment: @Optimus Your code is slightly wrong, use `mounted()`, not `created()`, it's different.

Comment: @Optimus for extended 3rd party plugin to work, you could just `import "leaflet-editable"` and it should be included.

Answer (score 0):

Correct connection leaflet and plugins - https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-gagarin-6od2q?from-embed=&file=/src/App.vue:223-263

Comment: That URL doesn't seem to work right now.